# toggle hide and show in different button

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i got 2 button, i want to hide one button when i click it but when i click another button i want to show the first button again

```
<a onClick = "this.style.visibility= 'hidden';"  class='blantershow-chat' href='javascript:void' title='Show Chat'><svg width="40" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs/><path fill="#eceff1" d="M20.5 3.4A12.1 12.1 0 0012 0 12 12 0 001.7 17.8L0 24l6.3-1.7c2.8 1.5 5 1.4 5.8 1.5a12 12 0 008.4-20.3z"/><path fill="#4caf50" d="M12 21.8c-3.1 0-5.2-1.6-5.4-1.6l-3.7 1 1-3.7-.3-.4A9.9 9.9 0 012.1 12a10 10 0 0117-7 9.9 9.9 0 01-7 16.9z"/><path fill="#fafafa" d="M17.5 14.3c-.3 0-1.8-.8-2-.9-.7-.2-.5 0-1.7 1.3-.1.2-.3.2-.6.1s-1.3-.5-2.4-1.5a9 9 0 01-1.7-2c-.3-.6.4-.6 1-1.7l-.1-.5-1-2.2c-.2-.6-.4-.5-.6-.5-.6 0-1 0-1.4.3-1.6 1.8-1.2 3.6.2 5.6 2.7 3.5 4.2 4.2 6.8 5 .7.3 1.4.3 1.9.2.6 0 1.7-.7 2-1.4.3-.7.3-1.3.2-1.4-.1-.2-.3-.3-.6-.4z"/></svg></a>
<script src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-1b93190375e9ccc259df3a57c1abc0e64599724ae30d7ea4c6877eb615f89387.js"></script>

 <div id='get-number'></div><a class='close-chat' href='javascript:void'>×</a>
```

Comment: Give the first button an ID, then the second button can use `document.getElementById()` to get the first button and set its visibility.

Comment: umm my second button is only appear when i click the first one, so how to get it done?

Comment: i mean i have a button that pop up a little windows chat. in the right corner of my little window i add some X symbol, 

what i want to do is when i click the button, the button dissasper in my little windows, and when i click the X symbol the first button can be shown again

Comment: Why does the second button only appear when you click the first one?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can put `onclick="document.getElementById('firstbutton').style.visibility='visible'` in the second button.

Comment: OMG THANKS U SO MUCH SIR work well for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an id and associate it with the click event.

```
<head>
    
</head>

<body>
    <a onClick="change1();" class='blantershow-chat' id="blantershow-chat" href='javascript:void' title='Show Chat'><svg width="40"
            viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <defs />
            <path fill="#eceff1"
                d="M20.5 3.4A12.1 12.1 0 0012 0 12 12 0 001.7 17.8L0 24l6.3-1.7c2.8 1.5 5 1.4 5.8 1.5a12 12 0 008.4-20.3z" />
            <path fill="#4caf50"
                d="M12 21.8c-3.1 0-5.2-1.6-5.4-1.6l-3.7 1 1-3.7-.3-.4A9.9 9.9 0 012.1 12a10 10 0 0117-7 9.9 9.9 0 01-7 16.9z" />
            <path fill="#fafafa"
                d="M17.5 14.3c-.3 0-1.8-.8-2-.9-.7-.2-.5 0-1.7 1.3-.1.2-.3.2-.6.1s-1.3-.5-2.4-1.5a9 9 0 01-1.7-2c-.3-.6.4-.6 1-1.7l-.1-.5-1-2.2c-.2-.6-.4-.5-.6-.5-.6 0-1 0-1.4.3-1.6 1.8-1.2 3.6.2 5.6 2.7 3.5 4.2 4.2 6.8 5 .7.3 1.4.3 1.9.2.6 0 1.7-.7 2-1.4.3-.7.3-1.3.2-1.4-.1-.2-.3-.3-.6-.4z" />
        </svg></a>
    <script
        src="https://cpwebassets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-1b93190375e9ccc259df3a57c1abc0e64599724ae30d7ea4c6877eb615f89387.js"></script>

    <div id='get-number'></div><a onClick="change2();" class="close-chat" id="close-chat" href='javascript:void'>×XXXs</a>]
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function change1() {
            document.getElementById("blantershow-chat").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("close-chat").style.display = "initial";
        }

        function change2() {
            document.getElementById("close-chat").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("blantershow-chat").style.display = "initial";
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```